# Bootstrap tooltip not triggering on badge

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, build, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a Laravel app for which I'm trying to trigger a Bootstrap tooltip on a badge, but am getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tooltip is not defined
```

I'm importing Popper and JavaScript components in `resources/js/bootstrap.js` as per the Bootstrap 5 [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript):

```
import Modal from "bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js";
import Collapse from "bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js";
import Tooltip from "bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.js";
import Popper from "@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper";
  
try {
    window.Popper = Popper;
    /* window.Popper = require("@popperjs/core");  # This doesn't work either */

    window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
    require("bootstrap");
} catch (e) {}
```

I'm initialising the tooltips using the following code from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/) in `resources/js/main.js` with a DOMContentLoaded event listener around it:

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
});

I've run `npm run dev` and have the following in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

And finally I reference both files and add the HTML in my markup:

```
<head>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

...

<div class="text-center mt-3 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
<span class="badge" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="My tooltip"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> SECURE PAYMENT</span>
</div>

</body>
```

So I've tried pretty much everything I can think of for now and am at a loss. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to put 

`var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});`

into a DOMContentLoaded wrapper?

Comment: @fefoweb I had just assumed that the initialisation JavaScript on the Bootstrap documentation would be all the JS I would need to get it to work, but I've now wrapped it in a DOMContentLoaded closure function and it hasn't made a difference to the error or the triggering of the tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this issue after coming back to it and spending a few more hours on it. There were a few issues at play causing my Bootstrap tooltips not to be rendered, and now that I've solved them the tooltips render as expected.

---

### 1. Adding a `title` attribute

As Bootstrap 5's documentation mentions and as Gleb pointed out, Bootstrap Tooltips require some data in the HTML `title` attribute as a bare minimum. This title attribute is used by the browser to render a default tooltip, which Bootstrap then hooks into to render a better-looking tooltip - so without this, Bootstrap isn't able to render any tooltip at all.

### 2. Modifying Bootstrap imports and requires

To fix `Uncaught ReferenceError: Tooltip is not defined`, paste in the initialisation JavaScript from the [Tooltips documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere) unchanged:

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
```

Then in the file you're importing your Bootstrap Javascript components from, such as `app.js` or in my case `bootstrap.js`, change this line inside of the `try` block:

```
require("bootstrap")
```

to the following:

```
window.bootstrap = require("bootstrap");
```

This should result in an `app.js`/`bootstrap.js` that looks something like the following:

```
window._ = require("lodash");

import Popper from "@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper"; 
/* Replace these with the individual JavaScript components 
   you need or, if optimising size is not a priority for you, 
   simply replace them all with import "bootstrap"; */
import "bootstrap/js/dist/button.js"; /* need or, 
import "bootstrap/js/dist/carousel.js";
import "bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js";
import Modal from "bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js";
import Tooltip from "bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.js";
   
try {
    window.Popper = Popper;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
    window.bootstrap = require("bootstrap"); // Modify this line
} catch (e) {}
```

Finally, run `npm run dev` in your build process - the error should now be cleared and your Bootstrap tooltips should be rendering as expected.

[image: working Bootstrap tooltip example]

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add a `title` attribute with text for the tooltip.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#markup

> The required markup for a tooltip is only a data attribute and title on the HTML element you wish to have a tooltip.

```html
<div class="text-center mt-3 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
  <span title="Some tooltip text!" class="badge bg-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> SECURE PAYMENT</span>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I realised this after and subsequently added it in an edit from 5 mins ago but while the tooltip is now showing, it's using the default styling of the browser which it makes it look like an alt tag rather than what it should look like. This and the Undefined error suggests to me it isn't actually Bootstrap rendering the tooltip, or that it's having trouble doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I noticed the answer has been edited and I was just wondering what the problem looks like now...

Comment: Like default browser alt tag text is the best way I can describe it, have a look: https://i.imgur.com/PK6NoOj.jpg.

Comment: [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript) suggests import code without `.js` at the end: `import Tooltip from "bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip";`. And errors in the console may indicate what could not be used. For example, Popper...

Comment: I can't imagine a missing attribute causing an uncaught ReferenceError.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Good catch. What's weird is that actually got rid of the error but the appearance of the tooltip remains the same even after running `npm run dev`. :/

Comment: My bad, false alarm, the error is still there.

Comment: @miken32 Yes, but the issue with the missing title attribute was in the first version of the question and in the OP's comments. So I used the answer to demonstrate that this attribute is required.